# Payroll in C Language: How to display records

Tags: c

Our professor told us to do a Payroll System in C language and ask for 10 employees. I really don't know what is next to do. So the program should ask for 10 employees and after I put 10 employees I can now return to 3 options to ask for all the records. The problem is I don't know how to display all the records in Case 1. It is a Payroll System in C

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct employee 
{
    int empId, hrW, hrR;
    char empName[30], taxCode;
};

void display(struct employee e1) 
{   
    printf("%d \t %s \t %d \t %d \t %s \n", e1.empId, e1.empName, e1.hrW, e1.hrR, e1.taxCode);

    return;
}

int main(void)
{
    int choice, i, ch, option, ok = 0;
    struct employee *e1;

    while (ok == 0) {
    // Choices
    printf("1.) Show All Records\n");
    printf("2.) Add 10 Records\n");
    printf("3.) Exit\n\n");
    printf("========================\n");
    printf("Enter Choice: ");
    scanf("%d", &choice);
    printf("========================\n");

        switch(choice)
        {
            case 1: printf("\nEmployee ID\t Employee Name\t Hours Worked\t Hourly Rate\n");
                    break;

            case 2: printf("       Witholding Tax :\n");
                    printf("Code:\tDefinition:\tDeduction:");
                    printf("\n\nS\tSingle\t\t500");
                    printf("\n\nH\tHead of the\t450");
                    printf("\n\tFamily");
                    printf("\n\nM2\tMarried with\t400");
                    printf("\n\t2 dependents");
                    printf("\n\nM3\tMarried with\t300");
                    printf("\n\t3 dependents");

                    for (i = 1; i <= 10; i++) 
                    {   
                        printf("\n\nEmployee ID:    ");
                        scanf("%d", &(e1[i].empId));
                        printf("Employee Name:  ");
                        scanf(" %[^\n]s", &(e1[i].empName));
                        printf("Hours Worked:   ");
                        scanf("\n%d", &(e1[i].hrW));
                        printf("Hourly Rate:    ");
                        scanf("\n%d", &(e1[i].hrR));
                        printf("Enter Tax Code: "); 
                        scanf("%s", &(e1[i].taxCode));                  
                    }
                    break;
            case 3: 
                    break;

            default: printf("Invalid Choice");
        }
        printf("\nDo you want to continue? (Y/N): ");           // Option choices if you wish to continue
        scanf("%s", &option);

        if (option == 'y'||option == 'Y')
        {
            printf("\n");
        }
        else if (option == 'n'||option == 'N')
        {
            ok++;
        }
}
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You seem to be able to read fields in option 2, why is it harder to display them? Using `printf` instead of `scanf`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the comments. To print all the records in case 1, all you need to do is use prinf.

**For example:**

```
case 1: printf("\nEmployee ID\t Employee Name\t Hours Worked\t Hourly Rate\n");
    for (i = 1; i <= 10; i++){   
        printf("\n%d", e1[i].empId);
        printf("\t\t%s", e1[i].empName);
        printf("\t\t%d", e1[i].hrW);
        printf("\t\t$d", e1[i].hrR);               
    }
    break;
```